# How to create a gitlab job to duplicate and change a folder in the repository and commit

Tags: git, gitlab, gitlab-ci, jobs

Here is the scenario
We are providing a telegram bot service to our users and we don't want to give them the source code and run the code on our server but we need to get some information from them so we've created a form in our UI to get the information from them after the form submission we need to create a gitlab job to do :

1. Create a copy from a folder in the repository which is the template of the project and change the created folder to of the variables which we got from user in the form
2. Change some variables in a file in the /data/setting.php with the data which we got from user in the form
3. And finally commit the changes to the repo so it will be deployed to the server with the CI/CD that we created before

Now I don't know how we can do this job with gitlab

We are doing this for our users so they can put their bot token and some other information and deploy and run their own telegram bot in our servers using a simple html form automatically

I've tried to create the job but I couldn't make it done completely